# laravel middleware runs after model binding

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-middleware

I have laravel 5.1 application that uses implicit model binding. and I also use https://github.com/romanbican/roles package to handle roles and permissions. The problem is that the route model binding runs before this package. so my middleware is running after the model binding which is bad. So if the resource doesn't exist in the DB, the response will be "not found" even if the user is not allowed to access this route. So in this case i want the response to be that the user can't access this route.

In short, i want the roles & permissions middleware to be triggered before the modelbinding.

Comment: Not familiar with L5.1 and can't find the model binding to be an actual middleware (which is for later Laravel versions which allow for more control), however in your case you might be able to do some checks in the [Error handler](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/app/Exceptions/Handler.php) and change the error to 403 if the error is  `ModelNotFoundException` and the user doesn't have permission to access the route

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding this is model binding. I just want me permission middleware to be triggered before the model binding

Comment: Unfortunately you can't in Laravel 5.1 since it seems that substituting the bindings happens before any middleware is run. As I mentioned in my previous comment this is unlike later versions of Laravel which have a dedicated middleware that does this and therefore you could probably add your own middleware before it.  Check the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L748) at where this is happening and how it changed over later versions. Overall upgrading your laravel version is probably a good plan if possible